# Customized view of ads in android using admob

Tags: android, admob

I want to display ads in android application, but i found ads only in the footer/header but I want to show ads as a shown in this image (just like gallery view).

Is it possible to display ads like this ? 
if yes, then how ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The type of ad you want is an Interstitial as opposed to a banner ad.

You can serve these ads via Admob mediation but you will probably have to serve them (via Admob mediation) from a network other than Admob because Admob Interstitial's are invite only.